# ggplot2: Parallel plot with varying yaxis depending on values of X

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data with continuous and categorical variables. This data consists of two groups, i.e. treatment and control group. I want to draw a parallel plot via `ggplot2`, in which categorical variables are represented as proportions of each category.

Furthermore, the range of the yaxis should vary, depending on the range of values of the reflected variables. In case of **continuous** variables, **the yaxis should range from `min(x)` to `max(x)`**. In case of **categorical** variables, **the yaxis should range from 0 to 1**.

In the end, the plot should look similar to the following picture, taken from [Iacus et al. (2011)](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/political_analysis-2011-iacus-pan_mpr013.pdf):

[image]

Here is what I got so far:

```
library("caret")
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

# Example data
set.seed(123)

N_1 <- 250
N_2 <- 750

x1 <- round(c(rnorm(N_1), rnorm(N_2, 5)), 2)
x2 <- as.factor(c(rbinom(N_1, 1, 0.3), rbinom(N_2, 1, 0.4)))
x3 <- as.factor(c(round(runif(N_1, 0, 2)), round(runif(N_2, 0, 2))))

# Create dummies for categorical variables
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
dv <- dummyVars(x1 ~., df)
df <- data.frame(x1, predict(dv, newdata = df))

# Replace dummies with proportions
df$x2.0 <- c(rep(mean(df$x2.0[1:N_1]), N_1), rep(mean(df$x2.0[(N_1 + 1):N_2]), N_2))
df$x2.1 <- c(rep(mean(df$x2.1[1:N_1]), N_1), rep(mean(df$x2.1[(N_1 + 1):N_2]), N_2))

df$x3.0 <- c(rep(mean(df$x3.0[1:N_1]), N_1), rep(mean(df$x3.0[(N_1 + 1):N_2]), N_2))
df$x3.1 <- c(rep(mean(df$x3.1[1:N_1]), N_1), rep(mean(df$x3.1[(N_1 + 1):N_2]), N_2))
df$x3.2 <- c(rep(mean(df$x3.2[1:N_1]), N_1), rep(mean(df$x3.2[(N_1 + 1):N_2]), N_2))

# Reorder data for ggplot2
df <- melt(data.frame(id = 1:length(x1), df), 
           id.vars = c(rep(0, N_1), rep(1, N_2)))

# Draw plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = id)) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = id), alpha = 0.5, lineend = 'round', linejoin = 'round')
```

[image]

As you can see, I managed to create a graph with continuous and dummy variables (represented by proportions). However, it feels like my way is kind of inefficient and I did not manage to create varying yaxis for the different variables.

How could I create a plot with varying yaxis in an efficient way with `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package for the data manipulation. I also normalized the values, so it follows the same 0 to 1 y-axis.

```
require(dplyr)

# manipulate the data
pdf <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(min = min(value),
         max = max(value),
         mean = if_else(key != 'x1', mean(value), value),
         norm = (mean-min)/(max-min))

# Draw plot
ggplot(pdf, aes(x = key, y = norm, group = id)) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = id), alpha = 0.5, lineend = 'round', linejoin = 'round')
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works better than what I did